# How to view Contacts Detail Activity

Tags: android, contacts

I have copied contacts local phonebook and have shown them in my custom list. While copying the contact list i have maintained each contact and his detail in an array. 
Now I want to open up the default details screen when i click on any contact in my list. Please tell me how is this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone whos looking for specifics:

```
Intent contViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,phn_user.getId());
```

Where getId return Id in String.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Intent.ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) Pass this action with a **valid URI**.

Comment: I have created an arraylist which contains all my contact information. Could you please show how to make a valid call to get details?..my code is as follows...

Comment: `PhoneBookUserEntity user = new PhoneBookUserEntity();
        // Pick out the ID, and the Display name of the
            // contact from the current row of the cursor
            user.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
           user.setPhoneBookName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));`

Comment: String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
       //    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
           Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ user.getId(), null, null); 
           while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
              user.sePhoneNumber(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));                 
           } 
        phones.close();

Comment: Don't post code here. Update your post, don't ask if its correct, try testing it and see if it works.